# How to read data content in jenkins using groovy

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I want to loop my repository to find all manifact datas, and then I want to read the content in the manifest data.

in my jenkins job looks like this:

```
stage('Read File'){
                steps{
                    
                    script{
                         def baseDir = "**/MANIFEST.MF"
                        def dateien = findFiles(glob: baseDir)
                        echo "datei: ${dateien}"
                        dateien.each{
                            echo "File: ${it.name}"
                            echo "Paht: ${it.path}"
                            def content = readFile(file: it.paht)
                            println(content)
                            
                    }
                }
            }
```

the error is it can not find the file.

any solution?

Comment: What's the full error message?

Comment: And there is a `}` missing for eachLine. Is it a typo?

Comment: is  "paht" in readFile(file: it.paht) typo?